# Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length

Tags: arrays, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import "./Product.css";

function Product({ id, title, img, price, rating }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="product">
        <div className="product__info">
          <p>{title}</p>
          <p className="product__price">
            <small>$</small>
            <strong>{price}</strong>
          </p>
          <div className="product__rating">
            {Array(rating)
              .fill()
              .map((_, i) => (
                <p>⭐</p>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src={img} alt="" />

        <button>Add to Basket</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Product;
```

Comment: Is rating a number or a string?

Comment: Check the value of `rating` prop since you're populating an array with that number of elements. You can set it up to fallback to 1 if there's no value, so it only shows 1 star for null value. `Array(rating || 1).fill()...`

Answer (score 0):

You will get that issue if the number is not an integer or negative.
You could use math to tackle some of the issues

```js
Array(Math.max(0, Math.floor(rating))).fill().map((_, i) => <p>⭐</p>))
```

Comment: now all star get removed  not working

Comment: Sorry replace 0.5 with rating